# Access- want button on main form that opens the main form as pop up

Tags: vba, ms-access, button

Is there a way to add a button on the main form that will open the main form as a pop up?

I tried:

```
Private Sub Command229_Click()
Dim newForm As String 
newForm = “FormAB”
DoCmd.OpenForm newForm, acNormal
```

I tried:

```
Private Sub Command229_Click()
Dim newForm As String 
newForm = “FormAB”
DoCmd.OpenForm newForm, acFormAdd
```

Then I tried:

```
Public clnClient As New Collection   

Function OpenAClient()
Dim frm As Form

Set frm = New Form_frmClient
frm.Visible = True
frm.Caption = frm.Hwnd & ", opened " & Now()

clnClient.Add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)

Set frm = Nothing
```

This creates a duplicate of the instance already opened. Is it possible to modify this code, to open up a new blank record form?

Comment: Another instance of the main form, or close the current instance, and reopen a new instance as a popup?

Comment: Why? Why not just set the form as a Popup to begin with? It is possible to open multiple instances of a form but never seen need to open duplicate as a popup. For a start, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152170/requery-multiple-instances-of-form-independently-in-vba-access

Comment: @June7 I don’t see a need either, but it was a request so I was trying to figure out if there was. I will check the link out thank you.

Comment: @June7 Also when I click the button, I want the instance of the form to pop up as a blank form.

Comment: Blank? Meaning you only want it set for adding new record? Then use acFormAdd parameter.

Comment: Is this form in Continuous mode? Most developers would have another form designed for data entry of a single record. Or have code simply go to new record row of already open form so don't have to be concerned about refreshing recordset of first form.

Comment: @June7 Exactly. I only want it set for adding a new record. Ok thank you. Do I use the acFormAdd parameter in the code I already posted?  It is not a continuous codec

Comment: It is in DataMode argument of the OpenForm command. Try it. I have never found need for multiple instances of form.

Comment: @June7 so I tried:                                                         Private Sub Command229_Click()
Dim newForm As String 
newForm = “FormAB”
DoCmd.OpenForm newForm, acFormAdd                                                                           Which didn’t do work for me; nothing happened when I clicked on the button.

Comment: @June 7 I added the code I tried above

Comment: You have acFormAdd in wrong argument position.