# Create mulitiple nondefault Instances with New operator for Microsoft Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I've a Microsoft Access form named `frmProducts`. To show simultaneously 2 products, I need 2 instances of this form. I've also `frmMembers`, `frmOrders`, ....

What's the general way to create a new instance of an opened form with its name?

The only working way is this:

```
dim frm As Object
Set frm = New Form_frmProducts
```

But none of the following code works (they are all errors):

```
Function duplicateOpenedForm(ByVal frmOpened As Object)

  Set duplicateOpenedForm = New "Form_" & frmOpened.Name

  Set duplicateOpenedForm = New Forms(frmOpened.Name)

  Eval "Set duplicateOpenedForm = New Form_" & frmOpened.Name

  Set duplicateOpenedForm = Eval("New Form_" & frmOpened.Name)

End Function
```

Please give you a method for this?

Comment: Can you specify the error you are receiving from the four lines you've tried?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710986/access-2007-vba-multiple-instances-of-form-update-controls-on-specific-inst

Comment: Thanks for all, I've checked those links, no general way found...