# MS Access VBA - Need help referring to a control on a multi-instance form, from another form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, instance

I have multiple instances of a form. I would like to click a button on Form1 (multi-instance) to open Form2 (single instance). I will then click a button on Form2 that should run some code that ends with requerying a control back on Form1. I am running into issues trying to reference the control on that form. From what I've researched, this can be accomplished by passing a for reference from Form1 to Form2 so that when the code runs, Form2 knows which control to requery.

If some kind soul with a better understanding of this scenario could elaborate on the thread below, I think it is exactly what I need:

[Access 2007 / VBA - Multiple Instances of Form, Update controls on specific instance from Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710986/access-2007-vba-multiple-instances-of-form-update-controls-on-specific-inst)

Comment: Never done multi-instances but from what I've read, need the Windows handle of the form you want in order to do anything with it, such as close. Search that topic. Whether or not that will allow you to address controls on that instances is beyond me.

Comment: form references are brittle.  I recommend adding a code module and creating some synthetic properties using public get/set functions and private variables.  Synthetic properties are rock solid.  You can call these functions anywhere in access.  when form 1's value changes set the property and get the property in form 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the handle of the window:

In Form1:

```vb
Private Sub ButtonForm2_Click()

    ' Pass the handle of the current instance of Form1 to Form2.
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", , , , , , Me.Hwnd

End Sub
```

In Form2:

```vb
Private Sub ButtonForm1_Click()

    Dim Form1   As Form
    Dim Handle  As Long
    
    Handle = Nz(Me.OpenArgs, 0)
    
    ' Find the calling instance of Form1.
    For Each Form1 In Forms
        If Form1.Hwnd = Handle Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not Form1 Is Nothing Then
        ' Do something.
        Form1!Textbox1.Value = Now
    End If
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. It got me going down the right track and now I have exactly what I need.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.